# Unity 2D Resolution gets blurry after building the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution, blurry

I am making a little project where it was working perfectly until yesterday. Somehow after build the game the resolution got blurry when executed and I even could play the game. The interesting part is the menu it's with the normal resolution, the only part that it was affected it was in game. Anyone knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all be sure that all of your Sprites have compression disabled in the build settings for the platform

[image]

Then it could help adding a [Sprite Atlas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html) which includes all of your sprites to the assets:

[image: sa]